# selenium, how can I select new window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc, popupwindow

I run my selenium rc test in Eclipse with TestNG. I have a link which tries to open a new browser page. How can I select this new page to operate in? I use this code:

`selenium.selectWindow("name=NewPage");`

however it says page not found. I also try to define page ids or titles with this code:

```
String[] wins = selenium.getAllWindowIds();
    for (String s : wins)
         System.out.println("win: " + s);
```

It does not define my new opened window:

```
win: MainPage
win:
```

If use `selenium.getAllWindowNames()` I get `win: selenium_main_app_window
win: selenium_blank65815`.

I write this code `selenium.selectWindow("name=blank99157");`  but get the error - `ERROR: Window does not exist. If this looks like a Selenium bug, make sure to read http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#alerts-popups-and-multiple-windows for potential workarounds.`

Answer (score 7):

The window obviously has no name, so you can't select it by name.

1. If the window is opened via JavaScript and you can change the script, try changing `window.open("someUrl");` to `window.open("someUrl", "someName");`, you'll be then able to select the window by the set name. More information on the [MDN doc for `window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open).
2. Selenium RC doesn't support `<a href="someUrl" target="_blank">` links (which open the link in a new window). Therefore, if the window is opened by a link of this type, you have to find this `<a>` element, get the `href` attribute and call

   ```
   selenium.openWindow(theFoundUrl, "theNewWindow");
   selenium.selectWindow("id=theNewWindow");
   ```
3. If it is opened via JavaScript before or during the `onload` event, you'll need to call

   ```
   selenium.openWindow("", "theNewWindow");
   selenium.selectWindow("id=theNewWindow");
   ```

   More information on this in the bug [SEL-339](http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SEL-339) or in the [`openWindow()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#openWindow%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`selectWindow()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#selectWindow%28java.lang.String%29) JavaDocs.
4. If you have only two windows / want to open the newest one, you can try

   [`selenium.selectPopup()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#selectPopUp%28java.lang.String%29)

   That is, obviously, the easiest way, because it selects the first non-top window. Therefore, it's only useful when you want to select the newest popup.
5. If the new window has a *unique* title, you can do

   ```
   selenium.selectPopup("Title of the window");
   ```

   or [`selenium.selectWindow("title=Title of the window");`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#selectWindow%28java.lang.String%29)
6. Otherwise, you must iterate over [`selenium.getAllWindowNames()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#getAllWindowNames%28%29) to get the right name (Selenium creates names for windows without one). However, you can't hardcode that name into your testcase, because it will change every time, so you'll need to work out some dynamic logic for this.
7. You won't like this: Go for WebDriver. It should be *far* more resistant to such problems.

Comment: i try variant 6. Wrote such code: String wins[] = selenium.getAllWindowNames();
     for (String s : wins)
          System.out.println("win: " + s); 
  
     
    selenium.selectWindow("name=wins[2]");

Comment: But get error:ERROR: Window does not exist. If this looks like a Selenium bug, make sure to read http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#alerts-popups-and-multiple-windows for potential workarounds.

Comment: @khris Yes, the link in the Exception lies, there are no workarounds mentioned in the docs. You can, however, try the workaround mentioned in my answer in sections 2 and 3, that's possibly the bug you're seeing.

Comment: selenium.open("url");
selenium.selectWindow("title");
this works, but this code opens one more window (first is opened after i click my link and
second - after those code, actually i need just focus on first, 
but selenium doesn't see title of my window after i opened it by clicking on link,
but see than i open it with url).

Comment: This could be ok, but i have another similar situation,
and as new window is opened with clicking on link i need select some record and it automatically is 
selected in main window. If i just open such popup as new link, i lose all previos inserted data,
moreover - popup opens instead main window and data is lost (it may be modified by browser options
 according open new window in new tab; i use ie and such option is checked, but new window still 
opens in the same tab that main)

Comment: What about `selenium.openWindow("", "theNewWindow"); selenium.selectWindow("id=theNewWindow");`? Does it pass without the url, or not? It has a special mechanism for this and discovering unattached windows, so it could help. By the way, what does `selenium.selectPopup()` do in your case? It won't help, I'm just curious :).

Comment: i get message - The method selectPopup() is undefined for the type DefaultSelenium, if i set some argument like window name or title - it said - window not found

Comment: it's according selenium.selectPopup()

Comment: in this occasion -  selenium.openWindow("", "theNewWindow"); selenium.selectWindow("id=theNewWindow"); - ERROR: Window locator not recognized: id

Comment: Okay. After some more research, please try the section 6 with a twist: selenium.openWindow("", "name=" + wins[2]);  selenium.selectWindow("name=" + wins[2]);

Comment: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: selenium.openWindow("",  wins[1]);
        selenium.selectWindow( wins[1]); This have no errors but i gues not work because can't execute following command (which should goes in new window)

Comment: And (without the `openWindow` command), is this the version you tried? Bevause what you wrote: `selenium.selectWindow("name=wins[2]");` is flawed, it should be `selenium.selectWindow("name=" + wins[2]);`. If you did it right and just made a typo in the comment, then I don't know what do do next, I really don't =/.

Comment: i wrote as in your example... it is smt weird, so many solution and no one help(

Comment: There is a solution #7, but you won't like it: Go for WebDriver. It should be _far_ more resistant to such problems.

Answer (score 2):

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebElement inputhandler = driver.findelement(By.linktext("whatever here"));
inputhandler.click();   
String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
Set<String> PopHandle = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> it = PopHandle.iterator();
String ChildHandle = "";
while(it.hasNext())
{   
    if (it.next() != parentHandle)
    {   
        ChildHandle = it.next().toString();
        // because the new window will be the last one opened
    }
}
driver.switchTo().window(ChildHandle);
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("something on page")));

// do whatever you want to do in the page here

driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not be using the correct window ID.

Check out this link. You might find your answer [here](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.DefaultSelenium.SelectWindow.html).

Let me know you this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try selenium.getAllWindowNames(), selenium.getAllWindowTitles()..one of them will work for sure.

Comment: Use selenium.selectWindow(MainPage) to go that page and selenium.selectWindow(null) to come back to the old page.

If that does not work then try this too

selenium.openWindow("URL","MyWindow");
selenium.selectWindow("MyWindow");