# How to handle nested popup windows in selenium webdriver with java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[Attached_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/genSa.png)

Please help, i am trying to automate a project(using java) where i need to operate on nested popup windows i.e with a main window i have a popup which includes one more window inside it. **You can check the image I have attached**. The problem what i am facing is,

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element
>   with id == btnSign (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 10.22 seconds

i.e. it is not able to find the element that is inside 2nd scroll. 
Note. (I am working on IE)
Can anyone give an idea how to handle it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium, how can I select new window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220869/selenium-how-can-i-select-new-window)

Answer (score 0):

You can switch any number of windows using  below code.

```
String parentWindow = webDriver.getWindowHandle();
Set<String> handles = webDriver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String windowHandle : handles) {
            if (!windowHandle.equals(parentWindow)) {
                webDriver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the reply. 
Will it be applicable for multiple scrolls as shown at image attachments ?

Comment: For scrolling you need to find scrollable element. and you can scroll it.

Comment: no help from the above code. And i do have a scrolling element. Once check the attached image for the further clarification. Thanks

Comment: Are you able to find/locate elements in child window?

Comment: Find element below for loop.

Comment: I am getting such error:    Failed to navigate to . This usually means that a call to the COM method IWebBrowser2::Navigate2() failed. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 18 milliseconds